# How to validate IBM MQ connection for Pool

Tags: java-8, ibm-mq, apache-commons-pool, jms2

I am developing IBM MQ Connection pool using Apache commons pool (2.4.2 ). IBM MQ JAR version 8.

As part of Pool concept , I need to validate the connection before return to program.

Help me on how to validate IBM MQ connection ?

```
 Java 8 
 IBM MQ 8  
 Apache commons pool 2.4.2
 JMS 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using version 2 of Commons pool.  To validate instances before delivering them to pool clients, you need to:

1. Implement `valiateObject()` in your `PooledObjectFactory`.
2. Set the pool's `testOnBorrow` and / or `testOnCreate` property to `true`.

Setting `testOnBorrow` to true causes instances to be validated each time they are borrowed from the pool. `testOnCreate` (new in Pool 2) validates only once, when the instance is created.

Comment: My question was how to validate IBM MQ connection. not in which method do I need to use for validation. Guide me on is there any Option IBM MQ connection give us to validate